# Unresolved external symbols in Visual Studio 2013 when using UHD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I can't seem to get a very simple program to compile in Visual Studio 2013. My goal is to incorporate UHD into a C++ program ([UHD Driver and Libraries for Windows](http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki/UHD_Windows)). I downloaded and installed the Windows UHD package.Since the library also depends on Boost, I also downloaded the appropriate Boost library.  After that, I wrote a quick test program in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <uhd\usrp\multi_usrp.hpp>
#include <uhd\types\device_addr.hpp>

using namespace uhd;

int main(void)
{
   device_addr_t hint;
   device_addrs_t dev_addrs = device::find(hint);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

In case anyone is interested, this program should locate any USRPs attached to a host PC. I defined the appropriate include paths in Visual Studio: [image: Include Paths]. [image: Library Include Paths].

To be clear, I included two paths to the header files: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\UHD\include` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost_1_55_0`

and one path to the library:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\UHD\lib`

When I wrote the above program, Visual Studio recognized the additional include files, recognized `device_addr_t` as a typedef, and didn't throw any errors. However, when I built the program, I received these errors:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::vector<class uhd::device_addr_t,class std::allocator<class uhd::device_addr_t> > __cdecl uhd::device::find(class uhd::device_addr_t const &)" (__imp_?find@device@uhd@@SA?AV?$vector@Vdevice_addr_t@uhd@@V?$allocator@Vdevice_addr_t@uhd@@@std@@@std@@ABVdevice_addr_t@2@@Z) referenced in function _main    C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\uhd_test\uhd_test\uhd_test.obj   uhd_test

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall uhd::device_addr_t::~device_addr_t(void)" (__imp_??1device_addr_t@uhd@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall uhd::device_addr_t::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Gdevice_addr_t@uhd@@QAEPAXI@Z) C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\uhd_test\uhd_test\uhd_test.obj   uhd_test

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall uhd::device_addr_t::device_addr_t(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0device_addr_t@uhd@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\uhd_test\uhd_test\uhd_test.obj   uhd_test


Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\uhd_test\Debug\uhd_test.exe  uhd_test
```

I've encountered these errors before in other programs, but I was able to resolve them relatively easily; either I would misspell a crucial include, or there would be an issue with a template class. However, in this instance, I can't seem to resolve the issue.

Any constructive input would be appreciated.

NOTE: In addition to defining the library directory path, I've explicitly added the UHD library, and I receive the same errors.

Comment: If you have used prebuilt windows libraries from the link you provided, they are explicitly stated as "compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010". In that case, you are likely seeing effects of _breaking changes_ introduced in Visual Studio 2012/2013 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx for more info).

Answer (score 4):

I got your example working. Here's the software versions I used since you didn't mention much in your description:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- VC++ Redistributable Package for VS2013 (vcredist_x86)
- UHD 003.007.002, VS2013, Win32
- Boost 1.56, lib32-msvc-12.0 binary package

Here are the project configuration properties you need to set in your VS2013 applications:

**C/C++** -> **General** -> **Additional Include Directories**

- C:\local\boost_1_56_0
- C:\Program Files (x86)\uhd\include

**Linker** -> **General** -> **Additional Library Directories**

- C:\local\boost_1_56_0\lib32-msvc-12.0
- C:\Program Files (x86)\uhd\lib

**Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies**

- uhd.lib

I think the last step is what's tripping you up, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I followed exactly what David Greene said, and I ended up with the same errors. Eventually I figured out that I had downloaded the 64-bit UHD, but I was using Visual Studio 2013 Express, which was a 32-bit compiler. Downloading the 32-bit version of UHD for Visual Studio 2013 solved the problem. For anyone else having this problem, double check that the compiler matches which version of UHD you install.